# How to login two user types (like admin and user) using single login activity in SQLite Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to access two user accounts using single login activity in android studio. There are two user types called "Teacher" and "Student". When I enter username and password, it should detect automatically whether user is teacher or student. If he is a teacher it should redirect to student activity. If he is a student, it should redirect to student activity after login. These are codes that I wrote for that. But it's not working. can somebody help me to fix this issue please?

**Codes in DBHandler class**

```
public Cursor isTeacher(String userName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + UserTable.Users.COLUMN_TYPE + " FROM " + UserTable.Users.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + UserTable.Users.TABLE_NAME + " =\"" + userName + "\"", null);

    return cursor;
}
```

**Codes in Login Class**

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user = userName.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();


            Boolean loginCheck = dbHandler.loginActivity(user,pass);
            if(loginCheck==true){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Cursor teacher;
                teacher = dbHandler.isTeacher(user.trim());
                teacher.moveToFirst();
                String type = teacher.getString(0);
                if(type=="Teacher"){
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Login.this,Teacher.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                } else{
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Login.this,Student.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend :

1. AndroidX Room for database calls
2. Single activity + multiple fragments with AndroidX Navigation component
3. Split logic into UI + ViewModel(LiveData) + Repo (database calls)

Then from fragment observe loggedUser LiveData and navigate to StudentFragment or TeacherFragment